# MySQL Read-Only column based

Tags: mysql, security, openx, advertisement-server

I want to lock some fields/columns in a MySQL-Database, is this somehow possible?

*Backgorund: We are using Revive also known as OpenX (of course the latest version) but it get hacked all the time. Especially the fields `prepend` and `append` in the `ox_zone` table.*

What we already did to secure the system:

- The Adserver is on a different Server
- The Backend is not at the default location anymore
- The Backend is secured by an .htaccess and .htpasswd
- We removed all install files
- We check the Core-Files every minute with the remote Git-Repo to ensure that we dont have compromised files (unauthorized file changes)
- We removed the file: `adxmlrpc.php` Because its known as entry point for attackers
- And some nice other tricks which I dont remember now...

But still sometimes the columns `prepend` and `append` are compromised, so I thought it would be great if we could lock these fields or set them to read only.

But I am of course up for any other solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad It's a third party software. It's like a product. I will not change the core files of Revive/OpenX then I will lose the update capability. Also how shall I fix Revive if even the devs couldn't fix it yet, since years. Of course you are right but the real world looks different when you have to use Revive/OpenX.

Comment: I would rather write the code from 0 than to use an unsecure product.

Answer (score 8):

You can set privileges on the column-level (and therefore only grant SELECT and INSERT) to the user that needs to be on read-only :

```
GRANT SELECT (column), INSERT (column) ON table TO user;
```

By replacing `column`, `table` and `user` with the appropriate values. [GRANT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

You also need to be sure *not* to grant higher levels (table, data or global) privileges otherwise it would override the table-level privilege.

Best,